# How to permanently run dockerd

Tags: linux, docker, unix

Usually before doing the standard docker process like this:

```
docker pull epgg/eg
docker run -p 80:80 --name eg -it epgg/eg bash
```

You need to run `sudo dockerd` at the background (i.e. with terminal open).

How can I permanently run that at the background without terminal open?

Comment: It is *not* usually - no one does like you said. Usually `dockerd` runs in background as a daemon (enabled/started after installation via `sudo systemctl enable/start docker` or other similar command, if you are not using systemd).

Answer (score 4):

No, better not run the docker daemon like that: `sudo dockerd`.

Depending on your Linux distribution you can use the following commands:

- For running docker at startup:

  ```
  sudo chkconfig docker on
  ```
- For starting docker service:

  ```
  sudo service docker start
  ```

These commands would work on RHEL/CentOS 6, Debian/Ubuntu.

If systemd is available on your Linux installation (for example on RHEL/CentOS 7), you could also use the following commands:

- For running docker at startup:

  ```
  sudo systemctl enable docker
  ```
- For starting docker service:

  ```
  sudo systemctl start docker
  ```

Answer (score 1):

For docker engine itself , use the `systemctl enable` and `systemctl start` as mentioned above.

But I think you mean running the container in the background, it should be like this:

First run it in background:

```
docker run -d -p 80:80 --name eg epgg/eg
```

then later you can still get a bash into it:

```
docker exec -it eg bash
```